# Elastic Beanstalk deployment can't find .py file in same folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am building a web app with flask and Elastic Beanstalk.  It works locally, but when I deploy using "eb deploy" the app doesn't work on the server.  Examining the logs reveals this message:

```
[Sat Apr 02 18:32:08.993040 2016] [:error] [pid 29804] [remote 172.31.46.247:64828] mod_wsgi (pid=29804): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/ProjectEiger/project_eiger_server/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Apr 02 18:32:08.993071 2016] [:error] [pid 29804] [remote 172.31.46.247:64828] mod_wsgi (pid=29804): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/ProjectEiger/project_eiger_server/application.py'.
[Sat Apr 02 18:32:08.993090 2016] [:error] [pid 29804] [remote 172.31.46.247:64828] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Apr 02 18:32:08.993109 2016] [:error] [pid 29804] [remote 172.31.46.247:64828]   File "/opt/python/current/app/ProjectEiger/project_eiger_server/application.py", line 12, in <module>
[Sat Apr 02 18:32:08.993134 2016] [:error] [pid 29804] [remote 172.31.46.247:64828]     from game_functions import *
[Sat Apr 02 18:32:08.993167 2016] [:error] [pid 29804] [remote 172.31.46.247:64828] ImportError: No module named game_functions
```

game_functions.py is in the same folder as application.py .  When I ssh into the EC2 instance and run the application there (as root in the virtualenv) it loads the module and runs fine.

I have changed the default location of application.py using .ebextensions by adding this line to my .config file:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: ProjectEiger/project_eiger_server/application.py
```

When I use the default folder configuration everything works fine.  But I'd like to use this alternative configuration.  Does anyone know how to make it find the file under this scenario?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Maybe the python interpreter versions are different locally and on the server? They did make a lot of changes in importing system between python releases.

Comment: If that's the case, shouldn't it fail when I run it via ssh on the server?  Also when I do not change the WSGI path, it also works. (edited to say that).  You're right though I should verify python versions are matching up.  I'll check that.  Thanks!